# How to detect git repository divergence with nodegit

Tags: git, libgit2, nodegit

Having fetched commits from `origin/master` with [nodegit](https://www.nodegit.org/), is there any way to detect that the local repository has diverged from the origin?

Basically I'm after a way to do the equivalent of the command line...

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged
```

I have tried using `repo.getStatus().then(...)`, but it resolves to an empty list.

Comment: I guess it's encoded in error code. Can you check error code?

Comment: no, I get nothing from the repo.fetchAll method - it resolves to void

Comment: `git status` is overloaded on the command-line and includes additional information (eg, ahead/behind count).  But that's not part of the repository's status, which is really just a union of the diff of the index to the head and the workdir to the index.  You want the information about the local branch vs the upstream to get ahead/behind count.  NodeGit may wrap git_graph_ahead_behind, which is the easiest way to get this information https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/e6cdd17c846648aa8e1e025fa1988475886a551e/include/git2/graph.h#L37   If not, you can diff your branch with the upstream.